# Codeigniter re-validate form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post, validation

I work with codeigniter for a couple of monts and now I have faced some problem.
I have a simple form with several input fields.
Lets say Name, address, phone, phone network provider.
So I set required rule to Name and adress, but phone and network are optional.
Here comes the pain. If something is typed in the phone field I want to set required rule to the network. I can make it with JS, but this its not the point. I want server side check too.
Does anybody have any idea how to do this in more codeigniter environment?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, where you're setting the form validation rules, do something like this:

```
if ($this->input->post('phone_number') != '') {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone_carrier', 'Phone carrier', 'required');
}
```

That way, the rule for phone_carrier will only be set if a phone number was submitted. Your validation will proceed as defined in the set rules.

Will that work?

Comment: I will try this way. I think thanks to your help I discovered my mistake. I should declarete rules only before form_validation->run() execution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>That is a common case and is easily accomplished:  simply provide the phone number rule, but do not specify it as "required".</s>

You could modify the forms validation module with some new type of cascading rules, but why not simply make the required checks yourself?

Comment: I think you didnt understand me well. :)
The phone field is not required, but I want when somebody types something in, the next field Phone network provider to be setted as required, but only if phone is filled.

Comment: That was the first thing that come to my mind, but I want to do it move "native" to codeigniter. I mean I want my code to stay clean.
Like I want to display the errors trough form_error();